# Is it possible to construct a THREE.Texture from byte array rather than file path?

Tags: javascript, three.js, client-server

I have a server client system where server parse the model file and send the vertex data to the client using socket. My problem arises when the model contains texture. I can read the texture(png file) to a byte array and send it to client using socket. But i have no idea how am i gonna create a `THREE.Texture` from the byte array.

So here is my question, is it possible to construct a `THREE.Texture` from the byte array? How can i achieve it?

Also, you can suggest other better approach to send texture from server to client.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you already have a byte-array from the websocket there is a more elegant-solution for this using Blobs:

```js
// assuming `byteArray` came in from the websocket
var texture = new THREE.Texture();
var imageBlob = new Blob([byteArray.buffer], {type: "image/png"});
var url = URL.createObjectURL(imageBlob);

var image = new Image();
image.src = url;
image.onload = function() { 
    texture.image = image; 
    texture.needsUpdate = true; 
};
```

you now have a proper URL (something like `blob:http://example.com/$uuid`) that you can use whereever you want. The major benefit from this is that you save the time it takes to convert the data to base64 and it doesn't crash the devtools when they try to show you the hundreds-of-kilobytes long string of the base64-url.

But there is even one more option (unfortunately not very widely supported yet): [`createImageBitmap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/createImageBitmap). With that, i would be as simple as:

```js
var texture = new THREE.Texture();
var imageBlob = new Blob([byteArray.buffer], {type: "image/png"});

createImageBitmap(imageBlob).then(function(imageBitmap) {
    texture.image = imageBitmap;
    texture.needsUpdate = true;
});
```

Comment: hi, i try to use URL.createObjectUrl function but i get the "URL.createObjectUrl is not a function" error. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @badcode that's really weird. According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL this has been widely supported by browsers for several years now. What's the platform you are using this on?

Comment: @ Martin Schuhfuß I got the problem :) . it's createObjectURL(), not  createObjectUrl()

Comment: arrgh, these things are so hard to spot! I don't want to know how many hours I wasted to these kind of problems :D Glad you found it!

Answer (score 2):

Okay, after some research around the web i have found a way to do it. I have to create data uri from the byte array and pass it to the `THREE.TextureLoader`. Here is the code to do it -

```
        let data_uri = "data:image/png;base64," + convert_to_base64_string(my_byte_array);

        // instantiate a loader
        let loader_t = new THREE.TextureLoader();
        loader_t.load(
            // resource URL
            data_uri,
            // Function when resource is loaded
            function ( texture ) {


                let plane = scene.getObjectByName("test-texture");
                plane.material.map = texture;

                plane.material.needsUpdate = true;
            },
            // Function called when download progresses
            function ( xhr ) {
                console.log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' );
            },
            // Function called when download errors
            function ( xhr ) {
                console.log( 'An error happened' );
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to follow some steps:

convert bytes to base64: jou can use a library like https://github.com/beatgammit/base64-js

create an image with base64 datas:

```
var image = new Image();
image.src =  "data:image/png;base64," + myBase64Datas;
```

create texture from image.

```
var texture = new THREE.Texture();
texture.image = image;
image.onload = function() {
    texture.needsUpdate = true;
};
```

If you have troubles you can check the conversion from bytearray to base64 with online base64 viewer like this:
http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter